# Multiple conditions always returning positive

Tags: bash, grep

```
#!/bin/bash
status_1="rebuild"
status_2="enabled"
status_3="disabled"
if grep -q "[alpha]" "/home/user/asd" && grep -q "[beta]" "/home/user/asd" && \
[[ "$status_1" == "rebuild" || "$status_1" == "reinstall" || "$status_1" == "install" ]] && \
[[ "$status_2" == "enabled" || "$status_3" == "enabled" ]];
then
  echo yay
else
  echo nay
fi
```

This should return yay only if lines "[alpha]" + "[beta]" are found in the file "asd" + if status_1 = rebuild or reinstall or install + if at least status_2 or status_3 = enabled.

However, it's always returning "yay", even if I remove "[alpha]" + "[beta]" lines from file "asd".

Comment: Sorry! I have just fixed it and tested. Still returning "yay" if I suppress [alpha] and [beta] lines from file.

Comment: Fixed it with full path. Still returning yay.

Comment: I get `nay` as output. What exactly is in your `asd` file?

Comment: A lot of lines, but none containing [alpha] or [beta]. Let me recheck.

Comment: Removed all lines and added a single line: ssdasda.
It returned "nay". Added a few more random lines and added only [alpha]; it returned "yay".

Comment: Can't reproduce: I get `yay` with a single line containing `ssdasda`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `[[ "$status_1" == "rebuild" || "$status_1" == "reinstall" || "$status_1" == "install" ]]` can be written: `[[ "$status_1" =~ ^(rebuild|(re)?install)$ ]]` and `[[ "$status_2" == "enabled" || "$status_3" == "enabled" ]]`  can be written: `[[ "enabled" =~ ^(${status_2}|${status_3})$ ]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[alpha]` is a character class that matches any of the letters `a`, `l`, `p`, or `h`. Use `-F` to interpret it as a fixed string rather than a regex.

```
if grep -qF "[alpha]" asd && grep -qF "[beta]" asd && \
```